# How to create mongodb schema with indexes using phpunit setup? (SF2)

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, phpunit, doctrine-odm

I want to create the mongodb schema ensuring indexes using doctrine mongodb odm.

I'm using Symfony 2, Doctrine ODM with mongodb and PHPUnit 4.5.0

One similar question has as suggestions using commands: [Symfony2: Creating Schema in PHPUnit only runs one command at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880111/symfony2-creating-schema-in-phpunit-only-runs-one-command-at-a-time)

But I want to do something more internal like:

PHPUnit code

```
public function setUp() {
    //Get kernel and create mongodb schema with indexes
    $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager')->  Generate Schema??
}

public function tearDown() {
    //Drop entire schema
}
```

What are my options?

Comment: I removed your last sentence and replaced it with a question

Comment: I tried to use self::$kernel which is provided by WebTestCase, but I don't how to get into schema generator using this container "document_manager", I don't even know if it is the right one. I'm really new to SF2